# How to make Python inquirer working in Pycharm?

Tags: python, menu, pycharm

**Hello**,
I'm trying to make an interactive menu in python console. I found python-inquirer should be good for my purpose, but it doesn't work in PyCharm when I run it, it just prints out the options and I can't choose anything. Does anyone know what my problem is and how to solve it? I'm really happy for any help.

```
from pprint import pprint
import inquirer

questions = [
    inquirer.List(
        "size",
        message="What size do you need?",
        choices=["Jumbo", "Large", "Standard", "Medium", "Small", "Micro"],
    ),
]

answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
pprint(answers)
```

**The code is just copy-pasted from python inquirer documentation**
There are no errors when I run it, it just doesn't work

Comment: It looks like that library uses special Unix-like terminal functionality. Maybe try [running the scripts from the terminal instead of the pycharm console](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000020339-How-to-run-python-program-in-terminal-instead-of-console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Run/Debug Configuration of your Pycharm project tick "Emulate terminal in output console"

Then you can use also pycharm debug features

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLLtj.png)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! - Problem was running in built-in python terminal in PyCharm, when running in console using `python 'filename'`  it did work.

Comment: but can you debug like this?

Comment: @rubmz yes, errors will pop up in the terminal

Comment: It's kind of working, but is problemaic for internationalized terminal (which pycharm doesn't seem to be) - right to left languages are printed backwards... finally... I gave up and input an index value in case I am in the pycharm terminal.

Comment: @rubmz If you have problems with integrated terminal, you can change it for powershell/terminal or other as you wish. You can find how to do this on the internet easily

Comment: The programs will still run in pycharm, but it will use for example the powershell.

Comment: The problem as said, the terminal even though seems to run bin/bash - does not behave exactly like one. Probably somewhere between the pycharm display of the terminal and the terminal display wraps around the characters... Another thing is input - inputs to the terminal are not like inputs to the console. That's why it would be great to simply run bash externally and still be able to debug (but in a separate console)

Comment: You can open bash, cd to the directory and then python “filename” / python “directory/to/file” and this will work if you don’t mind having another window.

Comment: Here you can see how to change pycharm default terminal https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html#configure-the-terminal-emulator

Comment: The default terminal configurations only define which emulator to run under the pycharm's own screen, which isn't what I want because I need proper terminal (xterm under ubuntu). I am still struggling on how to start the bin/bash as a process. Guess this needs some sort of an external tool + attach to process?

Comment: What ubuntu are you using? Server/desktop?

Comment: Ubuntu desktop... if it were windows (using some ssh connection to ubuntu) then pycharm might just work as is. Inputs (keyboard/mouse) have different behavior on windows.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your problem. You should be able to have more windows open (pycharm + xterm/bash) on ubuntu desktop.

Comment: I just don't quite understand how to setup the debug configuration for it...